# I am traversing the linked list in Python and when I am passing arguments, it's giving me an error. How can I take objects to see the result?

Tags: python, singly-linked-list, traversal

Consider:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self,data):
      self.data=data
      self.ref=ref
class LinkedList:
   def __init__(self):
      self.head= None
    
   def print_LL(self):
      if self.head== None:
        print("Linked list is empty")

      else:
        n=self.head
        while n is not None:
           print(n.data)
           n=n.ref

n=[10,20,30,40] 

LL1= LinkedList(n)
LL1.print_LL(n)
```

I was trying to test the code by giving it some value, but it keeps saying:

> LinkedList.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: What were you expecting `LinkedList(n)` to do?  The class simply does not take a parameter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. What do you need help with exactly? The error says exactly what the problem is. Check out [ask].

Comment: I think a deeper problem here is that there's no code that actually *builds* the linked list. It's always going to be empty, which makes it pointless.

Comment: `ref` and `data` are both not defined...  this code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you have sited is related to the fact that the class `LinkedList` `__init__()` method only has one argument `self`.

You should lookup what `self` refers to in python. A good example is here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp

When you construct the class, you call place an argument `n`, which means that the class which was expecting one position argument (`self`) is not getting 2 positional arguments (`self`, `n`) and it was not expecting this.

so the proper construction would look like this:

```py
class LinkedList:
   def __init__(self, n):
      self.head= None
      self.n = n
```

However, this would just correct the error that was mentioned in the question.

There are other fundamental errors with the `LinkedList` class which still persist.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this code snippet is super helpful. Instead I'd put the start of the next step, like `if not n: self.head = None; else: self.head = Node(n[0]); for x in n[1:]: ...`

Comment: @wjandrea,  agreed.  i was literally focussed on *resolving the error posted*. This is why i was careful to point out that there are further errors in the code that will persist if not addressed properly.

Answer (score 0):

At line

```
LL1= LinkedList(n)
```

You're passing an argument to the constructor (`__init__`), whereas it is only taking `self` as an argument, which refers to the class' object itself, and there's no code to assign the list of values to the linked list.

```
class Node:
    next = None

    def __init__(self, value) -> None:
        self.value = value


class LinkedList:
    head = None

    def __init__(self, value) -> None:
        if type(value) == Node:
            self.head = value

        elif type(value) in (list, tuple):
            current = None
            
            for node in value:
                node = Node(node)

                if not self.head:
                    self.head = node
                    current = self.head

                else:
                    current.next = node
                    current = current.next

        else:
            node = Node(value)
            self.head = node
        

    def display(self):
        if not self.head:
            return
         
        node = self.head

        while node.next:
            print(node.value, end=' -> ')
            node = node.next

        print(node.value)


LinkedList([10,20,30,40]).display()
```

In this code, I am creating two classes, Node and LinkedList, similar to you, but in my `LinkedList` class' constructor, I am assigning the input values to the list, based on their types (could be of Node type which we created, or list/tuple like you're passing, or a plain number/string).

Output:

```
10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40
```